# sql set all values to null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

i have to clean all rows, colums etc. in different databases on a sql server.

I try:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS VarChar(MAX)
SET @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT * FROM ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + TABLE_NAME + ']' + CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

EXEC (@SQL)
```

but with this I get only the rows.
How to manipulate this statement to

```
update ... set = 'Null'
```

and without where clause, because I want all of them.

Comment: you're pretty close already. how about update tablename set column = null

Comment: Drop and re-create the whole environment. (Have a script to do it!)

Comment: @Jeremy but how name the column for this

Comment: It is just a regular update statement. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp replace NULL with no quotes to set it to null.

Comment: Are you trying to "Sanitize" the data for use by another group or Vendor?  Otherwise, it would make sense to truncate the tables.

Comment: @Leptonator I thought the same but my friend told me that truncate is not enought to destoy the data completely

Comment: @sano - Are you trying to destroy the data?  Of share with another group?   If you are trying to destroy, you need to look into Data Destruction, degaussing, DOD Wipes, etc. You may also need to be sure that you providing destruction services per your Compliance/Audit Teams.  I would start here: http://www.killdisk.com/dod.htm and there others that are out there.

Comment: I don't think setting everything to null will completely destroy the data either. You'd need to ensure all the backups and transaction logs are destroyed as well.

Comment: The operation you're literally asking for is meaningless -- there is no practical application for setting every column in every row to `NULL`. This also ignores the fact that in any realistic database a lot of columns will be `NOT NULL` and so cannot be set to `NULL` at all. Per the other comments, script out your database (with Management Studio, for example) and create it anew with no data (preferably on a different server, or at least a new disk). To securely erase data, you need to wipe the underlying disk, not the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 'update [' + TABLE_NAME + '] set [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = NULL'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

This will give a row/query per column, so you will have to use a cursor to loop through the statements, or cut-n-paste to an editor window.

Comment: It give a 'unknown columnname' at TABLE_NAME and COLUMN_NAME back

Comment: @sano - I forgot to include the `from` clause.  Check out the edited query above - it works when I test it locally.

Comment: sry, but this set some to NULL on the Table Information, the data is allready there

Comment: what do you mean by "the data is already there"?  I would expect the data to be there - that's why you want to set the existing data to `null`, right?  To be clear, this query doesn't change anything by itself.  The query above should generate strings, and the strings are themselves sql queries that you can cut and paste into an editor window, and then run them to actually set the column values to null.

Comment: yes I want to set every row in every column to null but what Andy Nichols answer is right too, there are transactional logs and backups that ave to be killed after. Now I cut SlimsGhost statement and write a loop in a sp to go in every table and set every rw in every column to null. I let you know when I got more. Thanks for help

Comment: if you are trying to erase all history of the values, rather than just overwriting the table values themselves with null, then I agree, that is definitely a more involved operation.  It wasn't clear from your question that that was what you wanted to do, but let me know if you I can help any further in your effort.